# Chamar arquivo JavaScript usando Express

Tags: node.js, express.js

Tenho um arquivo main.js com rotas para arquivos html, mas também gostaria de adicionar uma rota para um arquivo javascript.

No arquivo main.js possuo o seguinte código.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


const rootRoute = __dirname + '/';
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile('js/index.js');
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("A aplicação está rodando em: http://localhost:3000")
});
```

O problema não é encontrar o arquivo, o arquivo é encontrado, mas não é executado o comando, é só printado, como se fosse uma mensagem enviada pelo método send do response da rota.

Esse arquivo deve só executar o script contido nele, nada mais.

Já tendei o método render, mas ele foi depreciado, depois disso não achei outra solução.

Obs.: *a função está funcionando perfeitamente, pois já testei nesse arquivo main.js*